# Google sheets array formula to split and transpose cells with commas into another column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I'm looking for an arrayformula to split and transpose all comma-separated values into a single column.

See my sheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RYOlt2HmE1oC31nGhRtpU5mu3mg0gz7UK9-exMVKQlA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, A:A), ","))
```

[image: 3]